# MSSQL data in to JSON object and display it in browser using java

Tags: java, sql-server, json, eclipse

I am trying to display JSON object when I type the URL. I'm getting data from the MSSQL databse and I am using Eclipse IDE.
in the below code it asked to download the file.

```
    @GET
    @Path("/DB")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Customer> getDB() {

    DBAccess db=new DBAccess();

         List<Customer> list= db.getData("jdbc/db_my");
        return list;


    }
```

but what I want is to display the JSON object in web browser.
 Ii is giving me errors when I use like this.

```
@GET
    @Path("/DB")
    public Response getEmployeeByURL(String ms) {

    DBAccess db = new DBAccess();

    List<Customer> list =db.getData("jdbc/db_my"); 


     ms= list.get(0).toString();


     String output = "object's first element is : " + ms;
     return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
List<Customer> list = db.getData("jdbc/db_my");
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

Make sure your header's content type is set to json.